# Java synchronized methods question

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

I have class with 2 synchronized methods:

```
class Service {

 public synchronized void calc1();

 public synchronized void calc2();

}
```

Both takes considerable time to execute. The question is would execution of these methods blocks each other. I.e. can both methods be executed in parallel in different threads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No** they can't be executed in parallel on the same service - both methods share the same monitor (i.e. `this`), and so if thread A is executing `calc1`, thread B won't be able to obtain the monitor and so won't be able to run `calc2`.  (Note that thread B could call either method on a different *instance* of `Service` though, as it will be trying to acquire a different, unheld monitor, since the `this` in question would be different.)

The simplest solution (assuming you want them to run independently) would be to do something like the following using explicit monitors:

```
class Service {
   private final Object calc1Lock = new Object();
   private final Object calc2Lock = new Object();

   public void calc1() {
       synchronized(calc1Lock) {
           // ... method body
       }
   }

   public void calc2() {
       synchronized(calc2Lock) {
           // ... method body
       }
   }

}
```

The "locks" in question don't need to have any special abilities other than being Objects, and thus having a specific monitor.  If you have more complex requirements that might involve *trying* to lock and falling back immediately, or querying who holds a lock, you can use the actual [Lock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) objects, but for the basic case these simple `Object` locks are fine.

Comment: Uhm, but only if the methods are executed on the same object. Otherwise they can execute at the same time because they are not static. There might be multiple `Service` objects, the question doesn't make a statement about this.

Comment: @musiKk - very good point, and one that's worth making explicitly.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can execute them in two different threads without messing up your class internals but **no** they won't run in parallel - only one of them will be executed at each time.

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot be. In this case you might use a `synchronized` block instead of synchronizing the whole method. Don't forget to synchronize on different objects.